# Qt QList - removeAll deallocating memory

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have a `QList` of `MyClass` pointers like this:

```
QList<MyClass*> myList;
```

When I call `myList.removeAll(someObjPtr);` it doesn't just remove the pointers from the `QList`, it calls delete on them internally. Is there a way to get around this or is there an alternative `QList` method that would just remove the elements without deallocating them?

EDIT: Internals of removeAll:

```
template <typename T>
Q_OUTOFLINE_TEMPLATE int QList<T>::removeAll(const T &_t)
{
    int index = indexOf(_t);
    if (index == -1)
        return 0;

    const T t = _t;
    detach();

    Node *i = reinterpret_cast<Node *>(p.at(index));
    Node *e = reinterpret_cast<Node *>(p.end());
    Node *n = i;
    node_destruct(i);
    while (++i != e) {
        if (i->t() == t)
            node_destruct(i);
        else
            *n++ = *i;
    }

    int removedCount = e - n;
    d->end -= removedCount;
    return removedCount;
}
```

As you can see it calls node_destruct, which does this:

```
template <typename T>
Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE void QList<T>::node_destruct(Node *n)
{
    if (QTypeInfo<T>::isLarge || QTypeInfo<T>::isStatic) delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(n->v);
    else if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex) reinterpret_cast<T*>(n)->~T();
}
```

As you see, there is a delete being called.

Comment: Sure, the delete is called on an internal node, not on your pointer. The `T* n->v` in this case was allocated by `QList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QList` has nothing to do with Qt 3's [`QPtrList`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qptrlist.html).

None of the `QList` methods interpret stored pointers in a special way. You must be testing it wrongly. For example, the code below happily leaks two C instances and never deletes them.

Perhaps you were thinking of `qDeleteAll` from `QtAlgorithms`? This one *will* delete the instances.

Note that `QList`'s implementation may allocate per-item memory to store your instances in, and will free that memory when appropriate. In no case will `QList` implementation delete a pointer that you store in the list: the only way `QList` interprets the stored data is via its type, and then it's only to decide whether the items are memory-movable, and whether they fit into a `void*` or do they need to be individually allocated. In fact, *all* pointer types are stored in `QList` as if it were a `QVector`, with a bit of room added at the beginning and the end to make `push_front` and `push_back` have amortized O(1) cost.

```
#include <QtCore>

struct C {
  static int ctr;
  C() { ctr ++; }
  ~C() { ctr --; qDebug() << (void*)this << "C instance destructed"; }
};
int C::ctr;

int main() {
  auto c1 = new C, c2 = new C;
  auto list1 = QList<C*>() << c1 << c2;
  list1.removeAll(c1); // doesn't delete the pointed-to objects
  list1.removeAll(c2);
  Q_ASSERT(list1.isEmpty());
  Q_ASSERT(C::ctr == 2);
  // we'll happily leak both instances above

  auto list2 = QList<C*>() << new C << new C << new C;
  qDeleteAll(list2); // invokes delete on all objects
  Q_ASSERT(C::ctr == 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`node_destruct` does not delete the objects pointed to by QLists of pointers. If you look closely, it only deletes `n->v` for large and static types. QList internally allocates large and static types on the heap, so the delete is necessary.

For pointer types, the `QTypeInfo<T>` specialization is:

```
template <typename T>
class QTypeInfo<T*>
{
public:
    enum {
        isPointer = true,
        isComplex = false,
        isStatic = false,
        isLarge = false,
        isDummy = false
    };
};
```

As you see, pointers are neither large nor static, so are not deleted

Comment: The type info doesn't matter. Even if you did `Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO` for a pointer type to be complex or large, it simply would be stored in a *block on the heap and that block would be deleted*. **In no case will your pointer be deleted**. It will be *destructed*, and such destruction is trivial, but that's because we must not forget that a pointer is a value type that can be constructed and destructed, as any other value type. Just that such construction and destruction has zilch to do with what the pointer points to. It's like an `intptr_t`.

Comment: @KubaOber That is my point. I think the OP misinterprets the line `delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(n->v)` to mean that the pointed-to object is deleted for QLists of pointers, which it doesn't! I tired to provide more internal Qt code to show that fact. Maybe the answer isn't that useful after all...

Comment: In the answer you claim that the type info somehow matters. It doesn't. Even if the pointers *were* large or static, they would not be deleted.

Comment: You are right, there is no way that QList will delete the pointed to objects. I  tried to point out the source of confusion, and give an explanation why one of the assumptions was wrong, based on the implementation of `node_destruct` only. (the second wrong assumption would be that `n->v` is the original pointer passed to `QList<T*>`, although it would be a `T**`)